# MySQL db sync across locations

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, replication, synchronization

I have a web app which stores data using MySQL.
The web app is internal (not available via the internet).

I now have to deploy this application across 3 (and possibly more) locations (branch offices).
They need to be able to sync the data (entries created at one location be available at the other branch locations).

Requirements

- local instances of web app + mysql database
- each location reads and writes locally / is on own network
- database is synced one per day (possibly through a script via SSH) so that each location has the same data.

The only way that I was able to figure this out (so far) is to create UUID (unique identifiers) and to encode each row with a source bit (for originating location) and sync bit (new=0, synced=1) then to write a script where I SSH to each location nightly and add rows that = my source and synced=0 to each location... I realize this is brute and not very elegant/reliable but I am not sure what else to do.

The client is afraid that if internet connection fails he wants to be able for the app to function locally, but still have a sync between other branches (via a nightly script or otherwise). As I said, there are already a total of 3 locations and possibly more coming in later this year.

Any advice on architecture would be appreciated.

PS. I am not connecting the database to internet because of security concerns. But am open to all suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: If there are no deletions or updates on your data, then it's a simple matter of inserting the new rows each night... but if there are updates or deletions, you are in for a lot of pain if you try to do it by hand. Check 'Replication' in the reference manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication.html

Comment: Correct. A major pain if there are changes (even none are forecasted, it is a dangerous situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You client is potentially costing themselves a lot of money in extra hardware, development, and maintenance costs with such an architecture decision.  Unless they have mission critical data entry needs it might be a bit of a crazy expectation to replicate the hardware stack in all branch locations.

That being said, they will still need to move data across the open internet to replicate data from server to server, unless of course they have their own VPN within which you will be setting this up. trying to have some daily process to migrate/merge data should be a red flag in your mind and a total non-starter.  It is a very complex problem.  What you are likely going to need is some sort of master-master database replication cluster.  Luckily MySQL provides you with the ability to do this.  Unluckily, it can be complex to set up and get it just right, probably something that might be a bit of a challenge for you if you are having to ask this question here.

As far as database security, there is no reason whatsoever that you should be concerned about having MySQL databases hosted on the internet, so long as you are taking the proper precautions to protect the server.  The would probably start at the network level with allowing access only to port 3306 (and 22 for SSH access) and only to the IP address(es) of the web application server(s).  That would also include setting up MySQL user accounts to only accept traffic from the specific known hosts you will be accessing from.

Comment: It is a medical office that has 3 locations. They want to be able to share e-charts across locations. Currently the hardware is not very expensive, Synology servers (~$1,500 per location = ok). They also use the server as local fileserver so they plan on the hardware anyway. I can open port 3306 and 22 and limit it to static IP from each location. The trick is in the approach to local read/write then update across. I know sync is very difficult. I've tried to research this like crazy.

Comment: I do have VPN server running on the synologies, and I VPN to each machine to work with the database from home. I also have SSH running.

Comment: I am also considering having this setup: 1.Read local (speed), 2.Write to a master server (an one of the locations). 3.Create a script to redistribute the master database to each location at the end of the day so they are all updated. Problem here is again Internet needs to be up and running. They are very scared of it going down and them not being able to see patients because of Time Warner screw up.

Comment: You might need to look at replication, or if you have a clear understanding of how the data is being updated into the tables (say there is only a handful of tables where data actually changes and it changes in a predictable way), then perhaps putting together a scripted migration/merge may be reasonable.  One thing you could consider is doing a master slave/replication where all writes are done to a single server, while reads are done on replication slaves.  This would be a much easier setup, but would prevent writes in times of network outtage from the locations that have read replicas.

Comment: :) jsut what I was going to suggest.  If you can live with multiple read slaves, setting up master/salve replication is much easier in MySQL than Master-Master and can give you near real-time updates on he slave (no need for sync script). Replication is also fairly resilient to network outage as the salves would just pick replication back up when the network is available. I hope they are not trying to do this over some cable modem though.  They really should get a proper internet connection. (not sure if you were talking about some "over the counter" Time Warner offering)

Comment: Yes, that is their current setup. Time Warner Cable "business" whatever that means.